# Eloquent Relationships Optimize Query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following models: **CardBoard, User, UserPricingPlans, PricingPlanLimits**

**Note:** Don't mind if there is something wrong with the models code.They are working fine.

**CardBoard**

```
class CardBoard extends Model{

   public function user(){

      return $this->belongsTo('Models\User','id_user');

   }
}
```

**User**

```
class User extends Model{

   public function pricingPlans(){

      return $this->hasMany('Models\UserPricingPlan','id_user');

   }
}
```

**PricingPlan**

```
class PricingPlan extends Model{

   public function limits(){

      return $this->hasOne('Models\PricingPlanLimits','id_pricing_plan','id_pricing_plan');

   }
}
```

**PricingPlanLimits**

I'll not describe that Model, its not necessary for the problem. But keep in mind that there is an attribute called **maxBoards**.

The problem is that I only have the **CardBoard** Model Instance to work on and I want to get the **maxBoard** attribute from PricingPlanLImits. So I did it like this:

**Note: I Already have the CardBoard Model Instance here!**

```
$maxBoard = $cardBoard->user->pricingPlans->last()->limits->maxBoard;

return $maxBoard;
```

The code above runs great, but the number of queries generated by this operation is an **overhead** to me. Eloquent do an **SELECT** for **every Relationship** called and I don't want all these data and operations.

```
{
    "query": "select * from `users` where `users`.`id_user` = ? limit 1",
    "bindings": [
    ],
    "time": 0.96
}   
{
    "query": "select * from `users_princing_plan` where `users_princing_plan`.`id_user` = ? and `users_princing_plan`.`id_user` is not null",
    "bindings": [
    ],
    "time": 0.8
}
{
    "query": "select * from `pricing_plan_limits` where `pricing_plan_limits`.`id_pricing_plan` = ? and `pricing_plan_limits`.`id_pricing_plan` is not null limit 1",
    "bindings": [

    ],
    "time": 0.88
}
```

Isn't there an way to optmize this and run fewer queries in a Eloquent-Way ?

Comment: Hello! Why is your SQL statements executes in 0.96 seconds? (it seems too long) What type of database do you have? Did you set up indexes for your columns?

Comment: I've replaced the original Log to not show anything important.

This query takes 0.64 seconds, the database uses INNODB (MySQL) as Engine and its running on a homemade improvised local server just for testing purposes.

id_user is the primary key.

Comment: If the server was on a SSD the query time would be faster.

Comment: I think you should add extra relations to your models. For `PricingPlanLimits` add `pricingPlans()`... And all missed. Then it'll be possible to use `where` method on this related models. [Querying Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations). Also you can query only that columns, that you need. For example: `User::get(['id', 'name'])`

Comment: Probably I'll use the pivot on Eloquent to express exactly my case where you have all these nested relationship you can just take an "shortcut"

Comment: PricingPlanLimits

I'll not describe that Model, its not necessary for the problem. But keep in mind that there is an attribute called maxBoards.

Comment: Can't you use Raw DB Queries for this case if optimization is the major concern and you need only one column in result?

Comment: Yes I can but I prefer to look if there is an Eloquent-Way of doing that, using raw queries beats all the purpose of using an ORM. Still didnt have time to try all those answers here.

Answer (score 1):

you can get a data in one query if you use [with()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) method.

**for example**: `CardBoard::with('user.pricingPlans')->get();`

so can optimize your query using `with` method.

Comment: **with** makes the CardBoard Model Query again and does all these queries above, actually make it worse because it adds one more query...

I already have an Instance of cardBoard Model, using **load** would've been better because it uses an already created Model.

Comment: I want some kind of INNER JOIN to avoid all those selects and reduce 3 queries to 2 or even 1 as all these models have an nested relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Previous comments were not too relevant to this solution...

**example**

```
$cardboard->user()->whereHas('pricingPlans', function ($plans) {
    $plans->selectRaw('price_plan_limits.id, MAX(price_plan_limits.maxBoard) as MB'))
          ->from('price_plan_limits')
          ->where('price_plan_limits.id', 'price_plan.id')
          ->orderBy('MB', 'DESC')
})->get();
```

Comment: Can you give me an example using the models above ?

Comment: I'll try to implement that but I prefer to use Eloquent Pivot ( Custom Intermediate Table Models ) I think the solution will be much more clear.

Comment: Now we have an example without an explaination, please think of the kids!

Answer (score 0):

I usually go in reverse order:

```
$maxBoard = PricingPlanLimits::whereHas(function($q)use($cardBoard){
    $q->whereHas('PricingPlan', function($q1)use($cardBoard){
        $q1->whereHas('User', function($q2)use($cardBoard){
            $q2->whereHas('CardBoard', function($q3)use($cardBoard){
                $q3->where('id', $cardBoard['id']);
            });
        });
        // Probably you have to improve this logic
        // It is meant to select select the last occurrence
        $q1->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        $q1->limit(1);
    });
})->first()['maxBoard'];
```

Totally untested, but this should be the correct approach to achieve your goal in one query.

Answer (score 0):

You probably could reduce the number of calls by using hasManyThrough relation (See:https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

In that case you'd have something like

```
class CardBoard extends Model{

   public function userPricingPlans(){

      return $this->hasManyThrough('Models\UserPricingPlan', 'Models\User', 'id_user', 'id_user');
   }
}
```

And then you could call it like this:

```
$maxBoard = $cardBoard->userPricingPlans->last()->limits->maxBoard;
```

To have it all in a single query you'd need fluent and real SQL joins, can't be done with eloquent (but then you'll miss all of ORM fun)

Answer (score 0):

Typically it is totally fine to achieve the result with 3 queries, a query like that normally take 10ms. But each of your queries is taking nearly 1 second, which is way too long. I don't know the reason why.

You are also able to achieve the same result with a single query though.

Your naming is a bit unconventional. I use a more popular naming convention, hopefully you can apply to your case.

```
class CardBoard extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'card_boards';

   public function user()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
   }
}

class User extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'users';

   public function pricingPlans()
   {
      return $this->hasMany(UserPricingPlan::class,'user_id');
   }
}

class PricingPlan extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'pricing_plans';


   // This is a one to one relationship so I use a singular form.
   public function limit()
   {
      return $this->hasOne(PricingPlanLimit::class,'pricing_plan_id');
   }
}

class PricingPlanLimit extends Model
{
    protected $table = "pricing_plan_limits";
}
```

The query to get the result:

```
$carboardId = 100;

$latestPricingPlanSubQuery = PricingPlan::select('pricing_plans.*', DB::raw('MAX(created_at) as last_post_created_at'))
                   ->groupBy('user_id');

$carboard = Carboard::select('card_boards.*', 'pricing_plan_limits.max_board')
    ->join('users', 'cardboards.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->joinSub($latestPricingPlans, 'latest_pricing_plans', function ($join){
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'latest_pricing_plans.user_id');
    })
    ->join('pricing_plan_limits', 'latest_pricing_plans.id', '=', 'pricing_plan_limits.pricing_plan_id')
->find($cardboardId);
```

The key thing is to have a sub query getting only the latest pricing plans for each user.